# Running single test in unittest python

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a test_method() in a directory /tests. I want to run a single test from the command line. Instead of using test_module.TestClass.test_method I wish to just mention it as

$ ./test-runner test_method

and let the discover decide the test_method belongs to which test_module and in which TestClass. I am able to get the test_module by running a search based on strings in all test_modules present as test_module is python file. But how to get the TestClass holding the test_method within the file? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that yourself, you ought to use [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with the `nosetests` command, or, better, use [py-test](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) (and [tox](https://testrun.org/tox/latest/)).

The classic usage with unit test is to add a main in your module:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

See the [Basic example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example) in the doc

The main function has parameters used to choose the tests to run. See [unittest.main](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) in the doc.